# Given $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot e^{-jwt} dt = we^{-2w^2}$, what the value $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y(t) dt$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

For a function $g(t)$, it is given that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot e^{-jwt} dt = w\cdot e^{-2w^2}$

if $y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t g(\tau) d\tau$, then

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y(t)dt = ?$

Any hint for that?

I'd tried to related Fourier transform with some derivative proprieties such as

$G(w) = w\cdot e^{-2w^2} \Rightarrow jwG(w) = w\cdot e^{-2w^2}+w(-2\cdot 2w)\cdot e^{-2w^2}$ but, i think its not a good strategy.

Comment: The expression for $G(w)$ does not match the one I would expect from the title or the first line. I've expected $w$ instead of $w^2$.

Comment: @Andrei G(w) is a fourier tranform the g(t). I'd already fixed my attempt.

Comment: Hint: It is easy to work out Fourier transforms of convolutions. Can you write $\int_{-\infty}^t g$ as a convolution of $g$ and some (standard) function?

Comment: I find $Y(w) = -j\cdot e^{-2w^2}$ but I stuck here.

Comment: This is my attempt: $y(t) = g(t) * u(t) \Rightarrow G(w)U(w) = Y(w)$. So $G(w)U(w) = \frac{G(w)}{jw}+1/2 G(0)\delta(w)$. So $Y(w) = \frac{we^{-2w^2}}{jw} = \frac{e^{-2w^2}}{j}$.